# Implement interface partially over multiple classes

Tags: c#, interface

Is it possible to have an interface with two methods, suppose `Add()` and `Subtract()`, and implement the `Add()` method in class A and the `Subtract()` method in class B?

Comment: No - if a class `A` decides to implement an interface, it must implement **the whole** interface - **all** methods and properties defined

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. If you are implementing an interface in a class, you have to provide implementation for all the methods in the interface. WCF contracts and services are no exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with inheritance:

```
public interface IFooBar
{
    void Foo();

    void Bar();
}

public class Fooer
{
    public void Foo()
    {
    }
}

public class FooBar : Fooer, IFooBar
{
    public void Bar()
    {
    }
}
```

You can apply the `IFooBar` interface to the `FooBar` class, because it implements the `Foo()` interface method through inheriting the `Fooer` class.

But in general you don't want to.